# How to make 3 divs fill height of parent container

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs (all of which have dynamic content) inside of a parent container. I need them all to fill the height of the parent container, so that they are all equal sizes.

I have created a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcam9gcj/)** to outline my problem in a simple way.

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.parent div {
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
}

.center {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 34%;
}

.one {
  background-color: #fcc;
}

.two {
  background-color: #cfc;
}

.three {
  background-color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one left">
    One Line
  </div>
  <div class="two center">
    Two Lines<br/> Two Lines
  </div>
  <div class="three right">
    Three Lines<br/> Three Lines<br/> Three Lines
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you give the parents a specific height, you are really trying to give the sibling divs the height of the tallest sibling.

Comment: Why can't you use a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the display table and table-cell properties, and ditching the floats:

```css
.parent {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.left {
    width: 33%;
}
.right {
    width: 33%;
}
.center {
    width: 34%;
}
.one {
    background-color: #fcc;
}
.two {
    background-color: #cfc;
}
.three {
    background-color: #ccf;
}
.one, .two, .three {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one left">One Line</div>
    <div class="two center">Two Lines
        <br/>Two Lines</div>
    <div class="three right">Three Lines
        <br/>Three Lines
        <br/>Three Lines</div>
</div>
```

**2019 Update using flexbox**

```css
#flexbox_container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.one {
  background-color: #fcc;
}

.two {
  background-color: #cfc;
}

.three {
  background-color: #ccf;
}
.one, .two, .three {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox_container">
  <div class="one">
    One Line</div>
  <div class="two" style="">Two Lines
    <br/>Two Lines</div>
  <div class="three" style="">Three Lines
    <br/>Three Lines
    <br/>Three Lines</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: table` for the parent. It's nothing wrong about using a table layout here, since it's a table, right?

```
.parent {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

See the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcam9gcj/4/